# Centering a Form - CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a two problems with a form that I am working on. Problem one is that I cannot get the form to center in the page. The second problem is that I have the submit button that won't center inside of the form.

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(233, 69, 0);
  width: 40%;
}
legend {
  background-color: rgb(233, 69, 0);
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
label {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 7px 4% 7px 5px;
  width: 40%;
}
input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 7px 0px;
  width: 50%;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  width: 600%;
}
form p {
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: rgb(220, 255, 220);
}
input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(220, 255, 220) url("go.png") bottom right no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
input:focus:invalid {
  background-color: rgb(255, 232, 233) url("stop.png") bottom right no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Please type in your information so I can send you the newsletter.
    <br>Required values are marked by an asterisk (*)</p>
  <form id="newsletter" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <fieldset id="personal">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40">
      <br>
      <label for="eMail">E-mail Address: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail">
      <br>
      <label for="favBeer">Favorite Beer Style:</label>
      <select name="favBeer" id="favBeer">
        <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
        <option value="Saison">Saison</option>
        <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
        <option value="Pilsner">Pilsner</option>
        <option value="Hefeweizen">Hefeweizen</option>
        <option value="Stout">Stout</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="comments">Additional Information:
        <label>
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>
          <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up" />
          </div>
    </fieldset>

</section>
```

Comment: Try this amazing site: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close the last two `<label>`s anywhere. The correct code is:

```
  <label for="comments">Additional Information:
    <label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="55" rows="5></textarea>
    </label>
  </label>

  <div class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

You need to edit the css to keep the button at the bottom with `clear` and to center the button:

```
.button {      /*     */
  clear: left; /* NEW */
}              /*     */

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* NEW */
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/m0g9tzxz/1/embedded/result/

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @TuomasK

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify margin twice in your fieldset:

```
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid rgb(233, 69, 0);
margin: 10px 0px 10px 5%;   <--- Bad
```

You should have `margin: 0 auto;` on the fieldset and all of the controls in the fieldset should belong to a div where your other margin is applied.

EDIT: This is a hack of the lower portion of the fieldset to get it to behave in the expected manner:

```
<fieldset id="personal">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40">
      <br>
      <label for="eMail">E-mail Address: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail">
      <br>
      <label for="favBeer">Favorite Beer Style:</label>
      <select name="favBeer" id="favBeer">
        <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
        <option value="Saison">Saison</option>
        <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
        <option value="Pilsner">Pilsner</option>
        <option value="Hefeweizen">Hefeweizen</option>
        <option value="Stout">Stout</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="comments">Additional Information:</label>     
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" style="float: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%" rows="5"></textarea>
          <div class="button" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;display: block;">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up">
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I didn't even see that. Thanks. How would I go about getting the Submit button to center.

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd `input { float: left}` affects all `inputs` including the submit button. Try  `input[type="submit"] {float:none;}`

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd: My first question would be why is the button and the textarea inside a label? The simplest method would probably be to get them out of the label control and apply either a margin or text-align:center to the div

Comment: @zer00ne: Actually, yah, that's also going to get in the way no matter what. Good catch.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - So your idea would be to take the div class="button and move that outside the fieldset and style it with margin: 0 auto;?

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd: No, I'm in agreement with zer00ne. The input float should be addressed first to limit it only to those inputs for which it is relevant. Although, the div/submit combo should not be inside the `<label>` element. And your label elements don't appear to be closed properly either.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I have made some corrections and edited the original post but am still stuck in the same place with the submit button. The form is center which is great.

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd: You still have inappropriately terminated label elements. If I'm looking at your form and guessing at your layout, you need to remove the columns from the textarea, set it to float left, width to 50%, then you need to set your submit button div to width 100, margin: 0 auto. I would recommend removing everything from the label with additional comments to the end of the form. Then add each element back in order until you get the result you're looking for. I'll post an edit that I made to your code snippet that achieved the final result.